# How to change HTML button onclick with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the onclick function of an HTML button using Javascript. Currently, when I try to re-click the button (with the new function) the console returns this error:

```
index.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: document.getelementbyId is not a function
    at lightmode (index.js:25)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:1)
```

Here is the code for the index.html file (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="mainbody">
    <header id="hdr">
        <h1>JAVASCRIPT</h1>
    </header>
    <input type="button" value="Dark Mode" onclick="darkmode();" id="modebutton"/>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code for the index.js file (Javascript):

```
function darkmode(){
    var hdr = document.getElementById("hdr");
    var body = document.getElementById("mainbody");
    var btn = document.getElementById("modebutton");
    body.style.background = "grey";
    hdr.style.background = "black";
    hdr.style.color = "white";
    btn.value = "Light Mode";
    btn.setAttribute("onClick", "javascript: lightmode();");
}

function lightmode(){
    var hdr = document.getElementById("hdr");
    var body = document.getElementById("mainbody");
    var btn = document.getelementbyId("modebutton");
    body.style.background = 'white';
    hdr.style.background = "grey";
    hdr.style.color = "black";
    btn.value = "Dark Mode";
    btn.setAttribute("onClick", "javascript: darkmode();");
}
```

If anyone needs me to add the css file I'd be happy to do it.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. It's `getElementById` not `getelementbyId`. You spent it right everywhere else.

Comment: What editor are you using? VSCode has many free plugins to help identify problems like this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_linters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var btn = document.getelementbyId("modebutton");
```

It is `getElementById` not `getelementbyId` . Notice the captialisation. Correct it and you'll not get that error. Yes, javascript is case-sensitive!

Answer (score 1):

It is due to this line

'var btn = document.getelementbyid'

getElementById is case sensitive